# Email confirmation and Password Policy Without ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, passwords, owin, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using `OWIN` form authentication in my project and not using any `Identity` specific classes that MVC templates generate.

I want to implement email confirmation and a password policy in my project. I'm not sure how this can be accomplished, as I don't have `Identity` related classes in my project as I don't want to use those. I am happy with the `OWIN` form authentication.

Is there any way I can verify via email and create a password policy by using `OWIN` form authentication?

Comment: how do you store the users?

Comment: Users are already stored in a Legacy sql server Database

Comment: could you show some code, where you create the user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert but Yes you can ,  To verify Email address you can send email with Guid as QueryString and add page to check id Guid is true and then flag user as confirmed did you mean like this ?

```
     Send Email as html :
    body = "<b>Wellcom Mr " + Username + " </b>";
     body += "<br />";
     body += "<b><a href=http://YourDomain/checkuseremail.aspx?       
    UserId=" + userId + " style='display:block; '>confirm</a></b>";


     public partial class checkuseremail: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string id = Request.QueryString["UserID"];
     if(id != null){ select user id if email correct redirct to success page  and flag user as confirmed} 

      else {redirct to error page}
     }}
```